# Bad ATA account

Tags: solana, nft, metaplex

When using `metaplex` `auction-house` contract, some users are unable to complete a `sell` command.
Confirmed that if the same `NFT` is sent to a different wallet, that wallet can `sell` just fine.

The issue seems to be bad `ATA`.
Initially , the `ATA` account that returned via https://github.com/metaplex-foundation/metaplex/blob/b7760611d0838307757b831505eaaffee25b1b2a/js/packages/cli/src/auction-house-cli.ts#L260 didn't have `owner` or `token` inside.

See failure:
https://explorer.solana.com/tx/4Y6ZBqeWH1yFvaEJ2Hv6mkCxqdVNt9GQ9iHq15PoJY5JVxmTzHJx3MSKABchMBaY3Jd5WY4HpeN4a9bSTQKEJv1Z

When sent to another wallet, was able to complete just fine.
https://explorer.solana.com/tx/GUybhU53qY56bu4j2raQyp7uecGLgaFge6GBvRNtX1u8gqDzocKk8MDg52upZV985UPW8FAregpwTv7JGyWdNwf

After manually setting up the `ATA`, still didn't help.
https://explorer.solana.com/address/Cu6Dru1j6PZa3f9K2acuqsHcaVDRxniFVqPPk7WX7RaC

Seems like due toe the token being `0`.

Tried finding the correct `ATA` by using `getTokenLargestAccounts` but then I'm getting `0x12c` which says `PublicKeyMismatch`.

Would love some help in finding a stable way to complete this, this is happening to many users sporadically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code that you linked, `getATAForMint`, does not actually create the ATA, which is why `owner` and `token` weren't populated.

The succeeding transaction that you linked correctly creates the ATA, which is why it succeeds.

So one way to resolve this is:

- Before doing a transfer to your user, check that an account exists at the address, perhaps by calling `getAccountInfo` on the ATA: https://docs.solana.com/developing/clients/jsonrpc-api#getaccountinfo
- checking that the `owner` field is the token program, given by `TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA`.  More info about ownership at: https://docs.solana.com/developing/programming-model/accounts#ownership-and-assignment-to-programs
- if the account exists, great, nothing to do.  If it doesn't exist, then you have to add an instruction to create the associated token account, ie. through some call like this: https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/blob/8eb2c3ce60bfe943e277eb172ba8e9ce9b6bdae6/token/js/client/token.js#L494

Comment: Sorry I didn't follow up. I added a check that ATA == largestTokenAccount and if ATA exists. Will create ATA and transfer to the NFT to it as needed.